# Add ng-class added to transcluded element

Tags: angularjs

I am using transclude:'element'. Here is my directive:

```
myApp.directive('transcludeElement', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: 'element',
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs, transcludeFn) {
      return function(scope, el, tAttrs) {
        transcludeFn(scope, function cloneConnectFn(cElement) {
          tElement.after(cElement.attr("ng-class", "{'myClass': myClass}"));
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

The ng-class is successfully added to the element, but it is not processed by angular digest loop.

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ted_pederson/rm9xhvnx/).

When the "Set Backgroun" button is hit a child element with the same ng-class works, but the transcluded element is not styled.